# Is it okay to leak statistics from data.stackexchange.com to other websites?

Tags: discussion, support

I've retrieved some stats of stackoverflow.com using my own queries and other queries made by others in data.stackexchange.com.
Is it okay to leak this information, including vote counts, account name, account profile page etc. to other websites?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can "leak" any public data that is available as long as you stick to the license.

The license is [CC-BY-SA 3.0 or 4.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344491/an-update-on-creative-commons-licensing) (don't ask) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).

So you have to "leak" the stats with a link to both the source and the author of the query.